# cakephp 3 original data in afterSave

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Is there any way to access original data in afterSave?
I would like to log the changes on important data.

With $entity->isNew() I could check if it was an insert or an update, but how can I get what changed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the original values via `Entity::getOriginal()` or `Entity::extractOriginal()`. If you want to get all changed fields, combine the latter one with `Entity::visibleProperties()`, something like:

```php
debug($entity->extractOriginal($entity->visibleProperties()));
```

This should return the original values of all changed fields.

See also

- **http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Datasource.EntityTrait.html#_extractOriginal**
- **http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Datasource.EntityTrait.html#_getOriginal**
- **http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Datasource.EntityInterface.html#_visibleProperties**

Answer (score 6):

As of CakePHP 3.0.4, you can either use Entity::extractOriginal(), which will return the original value of any field, whether it has changed or not, or use Entity::extractOriginalChanged(), which will only return changed fields.

With this update, to reproduce the behaviour described in the accepted answer, you will thus need something like:

```
public function afterSave(Event $event, Entity $entity, $options)
{
    debug($entity->extractOriginalChanged($entity->visibleProperties()));
}
```

See [CakePHP 3.0.4 Release Notes](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases/tag/3.0.4), stating:

> EntityTrait::extractOriginal() now behaves consistently with extract(). Both methods now include all named properties [...] A new method extractOriginalChanged() can be used to extract only the original values of changed attributes.