# CakePHP 3: How to get original entity data and modified entity data?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I create `UserActivityListener` to log user action when the do whatever like CRUD. But I've problem when want to get $entity field data:

Example: I've got the table `Users` (id, email, password);

```php
// I do override afterSave event
public function afterSave(Event $event, Entity $entity, ArrayObject $options) {
  //Log field entity
  if($entity->isNew()) {
    Log::write('info', $entity->get('email'));
    // This one is fine
  } else {
    Log::write('info-old-field-data', $entity->get('email'));
    // old data of field was fine because entity does not change yet
    Log::write('info-new-field-data', $entity->get('email'));
    // Wrong, entity not yet change, Please help me to get new data.
  }
}
```

How to get new data of entity in afterSave function?
How to check which field are modified, which is not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26548511/1127933

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for viewing my question. I found the way to solve the problem above.
I've moved my code to the correct Model event: `afterSaveCommit`

```
//I do override afterSaveCommit function in Table class
public function afterSaveCommit(Event $event, Entity $entity, ArrayObject $options) {
    //Log field entity
    if($entity->isNew()) {
        Log::write('info', $entity->getOriginal('email'));
    } else {
        Log::write('info-old-field-data', $entity->getOriginal('email'));
        Log::write('info-new-field-data', $entity->get('email'));
    }
}
```